# Dynamic Scheduler with java

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, schedule, spring-scheduled

I worked with the quartz programmer a long time ago, and now I need to create a programmer configuring it dynamically, creating a work from the web, setting the date and duration. Continue being quartz a good choice or there are better options?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I've recently re-built an entire application for scheduling jobs.
For the "back-end" part I'm on the Spring Boot stack, exposing a series of REST endpoints.

Each (or multiple) scheduled job is persisted in a `XML` file, which is monitored for modifications, and updated via Quartz in case.
The scheduling part is delegated to the Quartz `StdScheduler`, and `Job`(s) are stored durably (doing so requires manual cleanup).
Seems it works fine even for huge amounts of scheduled `Job`(s), with multiple `Trigger`(s) each.

I'd say it is a great choice.